# How to send message to all servers discord py

Tags: python, discord

hi so what i want to do is send a message to all the servers my bot is in heres my code i am pretty sure this is not against tos but correct me if it is

```
await bot.wait_until_ready()
channels = []
for server in client.servers:
  for channel in server.channels:
     channels.append(channel)
      Message.send('HELLO! and thank you for adding this amazing bot. yes i am the owner ELONI sending this message saying thanks. thanks for getting us verified thanks for everythng. have a great DAY')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for guild in client.guilds: # guild stands for server
    for channel in guild.channels:
        if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel): # Check if channel is a text channel
            await channel.send("Hi")
```

You can add that to events or commands if you are using Discord.py-Rewrite.

Example Event:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds: # guild stands for server
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel): # Check if channel is a text channel
                await channel.send("Hi")
```

Example Command:

```py
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    for guild in client.guilds: # guild stands for server
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel): # Check if channel is a text channel
                await channel.send("Hi")
```